# Configuration for debugging stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, debugging, stored-procedures

I want to debug a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 r2, but when I debug it, the specific message is displayed.i.e

> Failed to start debugger
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_enable_sql_debug',
>   database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'. (Microsoft SQL Server,
>   Error: 229)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1600&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=229&LinkId=20476

Please tell me if anybody has some solution, Thanks

Answer (score 7):

SQL Debugging requires **sysadmin** permission.

Read more at [Error: User Could Not Execute Stored Procedure sp_enable_sql_debug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241735.aspx) and [How to: Set SQL Server Permissions for Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1bhybwz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Please vote on Microsoft Connect for a resolution to this issue, [MSIT-MSO: Debugging SQL Query fails with an error The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_enable_sql_debug' (ID: 351698)](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/351698/msit-mso-debugging-sql-query-fails-with-an-error-the-execute-permission-was-denied-on-the-object-sp-enable-sql-debug)